# What does `parity db kill` kill exactly?

Tags: parity

When I run

```
parity --config node.toml db kill
```

I expect that the node will resync from scratch (will start importing snapshots etc, or from block#0) however it seems to continue importing blocks from the last one. Though I see a line `DB deleted` in logs. So what gets deleted actually?

Answer (score 1):

One of the Parity folks can confirm, but I think `kill` expects an argument. From the `--help` output:

```
parity db kill [options]
```

Similarly, from the [wiki](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/FAQ:-Backup,-Restore,-and-Files#how-to-delete-the-blockchain-to-initiate-full-re-sync-without-deleting-wallet-info):

> - Stop parity, then execute parity db kill.
> - Relevant options are --chain=* --pruning=* and --db-path/--base-path, i.e. to delete morden run:
>     `parity db kill --chain=morden`

So passing it no options perhaps runs the process as a no-op, rather than deleting all data.